# Replacing nulls in table with space

Tags: c#, webforms

We have a SQL table which has a cost column containing several NULL entries.

So before binding this table to a grid view, I would like to replace it with space.

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
 if (row["AverageCost"] is System.DBNull)
 {
   row["AverageCost"] = Convert.ToDecimal("0.00"); // works
   row["AverageCost"] = " "; // doesnt work
   row["AverageCost"] = Convert.ToDecimal(" "); // doesnt work
 }
}
```

I would like to have the grid contain empty string and not 0.00.

Please suggest.

Comment: The column, is it decimal? nvarchar? varchar? What is it?

Comment: What errors are you getting from the examples that don't work?

Comment: I would add a new column named AvgCostText and assign that the correct values.  You won't be able to assign a column of type Decimal to a "space".

Comment: Its decimal on an ASP.NET Web form page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, it appears that the column AverageCost is a decimal field.  You won't be able to assign this to a "space".

You could, however, add a new column that contains the text representation of AverageCost...

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("AverageCostText", typeof(String));
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
     row["AverageCostText"] = (row["AverageCost"] == DBNull.Value) ? string.Empty : string.Format("{0}", row["AverageCost"]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to account for that, would be to ensure your column is a `VarChar` or `NVarChar` for instance.  A text field, rather than a numeric like you currently have.  Once you've modified the column type, you would be able to assign a `space`.

However, the `null` that your attempting to replace is designed for exactly that scenario:

- Valid numeric value (Example: 5.00)
- Valid numeric value (Example: 0.00)

Those two instances actually represent that the value exist via the user, which contains a useful representation for you.  The third choice:

- `Null`

That actually will indicate that the user hasn't modified said value, which is an indicator to you.  In essence it is a viable option for controlling the state of that field.  Which if you had a text field you would have:

- Valid Value ("5.00")
- Valid Value (" " or compared to numeric 0.00)
- `null`

So the question is, why would the space be better suited than the `null` or `0.00`?  Under most circumstances it will meet your criteria correctly.

Otherwise to perform said change you would need:

```
example.Tables[0].Columns.Add("...", typeof(string));
foreach(var row in example.Tables[0].Rows)
{
     if(row["AverageCost"] != DBNull.Value)
          row["AverageCostText"] = row["AverageCost"].ToString();
      else { row["AverageCostText"] = String.Empty; }
}
```

This would ensure the proper value is placed into your text field, but obviously the drawback should you need a decimal you'll always have to parse it.  Hopefully this clarifies for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a whitespace character (type `char`) to a column of type `decimal`. It might be useful for you to assign a `0` instead a whitespace.